# Adding values into session array

Tags: php, session-variables

I am creating a shopping cart application. I have the logic of adding each item into a session array but i don't know how to add the values into a session array. Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its very simple to add values to session array.

1.Add below line to the top of your script to start session.

```
session_start();
```

2.Use below examples to add values to session array.

```
$_SESSION['variable1'] = "Test1"; 
$_SESSION['variable2'] = "Test2";
```

3.Retrieve those session array values like below example.

```
//Prints whole session array by using below line 
print_r($_SESSION); 
//print individual values by using below examples 
echo isset($_SESSION['variable1']) ? $_SESSION['variable1'] : '';
echo isset($_SESSION['variable2']) ? $_SESSION['variable2'] : '';
```

Please let me know if you still find any problems

Answer (score 0):

add each item to an array and assign it to session variable like this

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['cart'] = array( ... );
```

so you can access each item like this

```
$_SESSION['cart'][0]
$_SESSION['cart'][1]
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
session_start();// First of all start session    
$_SESSION['arry_key_may_be_your_name']='My name';// Add values to session array
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please expand your answer to explain what your code does and how it answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Add Item into SESSION use the below Codes.. PHP SESSION

```
<h3>PHP SESSION :Store Multiple User Info In PHP SESSION --codenair.com</h3>
<form method="POST">
 <table>
  <tr>
 <td>UserName:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="name" required/></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Email</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="email" required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td></td>
 <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add User"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
 </form>
<?php
 session_start(); 
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $user=array(
'name'=>$_POST['name'], //Username form field name
'email'=>$_POST['email'] //email form field name
);
$_SESSION['student'][]=$user;  
}
if(isset($_GET['remove'])){
unset($_SESSION['student']);
 //Redirecting After Unset SESSION
  header('location:index.php');
  }
 ?>
 <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['student'])){?>
  <table class="table" cellspacing="0" border="1"> 
  <tr>
   <th>Serial</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
   </tr>
 <?php for($i = 0 ; $i < count($_SESSION['student']) ; $i++) {?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $_SESSION['student'][$i]['name'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $_SESSION['student'][$i]['email'];?></td>
  </tr>
 <?php }  ?>
 </table>
 <a href="index.php?remove=remove">Empty User</a>
 <?php }else{
  echo "You have no User in SESSION";
 }?>
```