# How to get session array values in php?

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-variables

I am working on ecommerce site. And i have following cart class which push or increment  product in cart And do other stuff.

```
class cart{


public static function add($request)
{
        try {
            if(!isset($_SESSION['user_cart'][$request['product_id']]) || $_SESSION['user_cart'][$request['product_id']] < 1) 
            {
                    $_SESSION['user_cart'][$request['product_id']]
                    [$request['size_id']] =  1;
            } 
            else {
                if(!isset($_SESSION['user_cart'][$request['product_id']][$request['size_id']])){
                    $_SESSION['user_cart'][$request['product_id']]
                    [$request['size_id']] =  1;   
                } else {
                    $qty = $_SESSION['user_cart'][$request['product_id']][$request['size_id']];
                    $_SESSION['user_cart'][$request['product_id']]
                    [$request['size_id']] =  $qty + 1; 
                }
                    
            }
        }
    catch (\Exception $ex){
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
public static function removeItem($index)
{
    if(count(Session::get('user_cart')) <= 1){
        self::clear();
    }else{
        unset($_SESSION['user_cart'][$index]);
        sort($_SESSION['user_cart']);
    }
}

public static function clear()
{
    Session::remove('user_cart');
}}
```

And i have following controller class to read and get the item from user cart and return to blade using 'jason'. My blade working but i am not able to get the cart items from function below.

```
public function getCartItems()
{
    try{
        $result = array();
        $cartTotal = 0;
        if(!Session::has('user_cart') || count(Session::get('user_cart')) < 1){
            echo json_encode(['fail' => "No item in the cart"]);
            exit;
        }
        $index = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION['user_cart'] as $cart_items){
            $productId = $cart_items['product_id'];
            $quantity = $cart_items['quantity']; 
            // $size_id = $cart_items['size_id'];
            
            if($cart_items['size_id'] == null){
                $size_id = 1;
            }else{
                $size_id = $cart_items['size_id'];
            }

            $item = Product::where('id', $productId)->first();
            $stock = Productattribute::where('product_id', $productId)->sum('quntity');
            $size = Size::where('id', $size_id)->first();


           
            if(!$item) { continue; }

            // check if product is in hotsales or not

            if($item->product_on == 1){
                $price = $item->sales_price;
            }else{
                $price = $item->price;
            }
    
            $totalPrice = $price * $quantity;
            $cartTotal = $totalPrice + $cartTotal;
            $totalPrice = number_format($totalPrice, 2);
            
            array_push($result, [
                'id' => $item->id,
                'title' => $item->title,
                'image' => $item->product_image_path,
                'price' => $price,
                'total' => $totalPrice,
                'quantity' => $quantity,
                'stock' => $stock,
                'size'  => $size->name,
                'index' => $index
            ]);
            $index++;
        }

        $cartTotal = number_format($cartTotal, 2);
        echo json_encode(['items' => $result, 'cartTotal' => $cartTotal]);

        exit;
    }catch (\Exception $ex){
        echo $ex->getMessage() .' '.$ex->getLine();
        //log this in database or email admin
    }
}
```

}

what i am doing wrong here. Is there any other way to read values from array that i have.
I am getting following array from session.How should read the data? In getcart function of  cart controller.

```
Array
(
[4] => Array
    (
        [3] => 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [3] => 6
        [4] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [3] => 1
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [4] => 1
        [3] => 1
    )
```

)

Comment: do you have data on session ? did you checked ?

Comment: yeah. i have checked.

Comment: Please show dd results of getCartItems dd($_SESSION['user_cart']);

Comment: before that i was geting data after that problem started. thanks for your time

Comment: okay good luck, that was my suspect that session is not setting.

Comment: @atikurrahman  you here?

Answer (score 0):

this answer could solve https://stackoverflow.com/a/21575447/6887279
by using `session_start();` to initiate session.

Comment: Welcome to SO! try to add your comment if you are referencing the answer or else try to paste your own answer

Comment: my problem is getting data in function getcartitems of cartcontroller class.